# Protocols used in a distributed/dlt system for the nodes to establish communication

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin, hashgraph

What is the underlying protocol used by the nodes to establish an initial communication with each other in distributed/distributed ledger technology?

For instance: Cassandra uses TCP to learn about other nodes.

Likewise, what protocol is used by

Bitcoin   - ? 
Ethereum  - ?
Hashgraph - TCP?

I am not sure if this question too broad to address. Please give some pointers to get answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

yes all are over `TCP/IP` connections secured by `TLS` encryption in `hashgraph` [architecture-hashgraph](https://cryptoticker.io/hedera-hashgraph-architecture/), `[wiki-etherum-netwroking](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/Network_Ports,_Files_And_Directories)
, [lightning-is-bitcoins-tcp-ip](https://medium.com/@melik_87377/lightning-network-enables-unicast-transactions-in-bitcoin-lightning-is-bitcoins-tcp-ip-stack-8ec1d42c14f5)